# While loop and conditions

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a menu where the user must enter an integer between 1-200, otherwise, the program will loop until the condition is satisfied. Below is the current code I have but it does not work as entering any number between 2 and 99 won't work. Can anyone help?

```
if option == "1":
        Width = input("Enter rows (must be an integer between 1-200): ")
        while Width.isdigit() is False:
            Width = input("Enter rows(must be an integer): ")
        while Width < "1" or Width > "200":
            Width = input("Enter rows(must be between 1-200): ")
        Width = int(Width)
```

Comment: `while Width < "1" or Width > "200"`? Why the quotes???

Comment: @goodvibration probably because they got an error that they couldn't compare a string to an int. Width should be cast as an int earlier instead.

Comment: Then just do `while not (Width.isdigit() and 1 <= int(Width) <= 200)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle problems here, but the big one is that string compares don't work numerically. `"3" > "200"` for instance, and `"1000000" < "9"`.

The subtler problem is that you're only checking `isdigit` once, then potentially prompting for input again afterwards. If I entered `9000000` at the first prompt, then `\` at the second prompt, your code would crash with a `TypeError` when trying to call `int(r'\')`

You should instead do all your validation at once. The canonical idiom for this is:

```py
while True:
    value = input("some prompt")
    if not some_validation_rule(value):
        print("Some error message")
        continue
    elif not some_other_validation_rule(value):
        print("A different error message")
        continue
    # etc, until
    break
```

This ensures that every validation case is handled differently, and you run each one every time you prompt for input. Once no validation case fails, you break out of the infinite loop.

That said, for this particular instance, you should prefer EAFP to LBYL, and just try to convert to `int` and catch the failure.

```py
while True:
    rows = input("Enter rows (1-200): ")
    try:
        rows = int(rows)
    except TypeError:
        print("rows must be a number")
        continue

    if not 1 <= rows <= 200:
        print("rows must be between 1 and 200")
        continue

    break
```

Comment: Ohhhh, that's a much better way for validation thank you.

Comment: @NaponFire if I have a lot of validation to do in my script I'll often abstract a "validation rule" out into its own type with two attributes: a function to run that returns True or False to validate the data, and an error message to return if it fails. Then all I have to do is write validators and pass them in as a list to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int(input("input description"))` and don't do greater-than or lower-than comparisons with strings. So something like this might work:

```py
if option == "1":
        try:
            Width = int(input("Enter rows (must be an integer between 1-200): "))
            while int(Width) < 1 or int(Width) > 200:
                Width = input("Enter rows(must be between 1-200): ")
            Width = int(Width)
        except ValueError:
            Width = int(input("Enter rows (must be an integer between 1-200): "))
```

edit: somebody gave maybe a lot better answer while I was drafting this...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go along with:

```
while True:
    userInput = input("Enter rows (must be an integer between 1-200): ")
    if userInput.isdigit() and 1 <= int(userInput) <= 200:
        break
width = int(userInput)
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if  you enter a string first, I got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'z'

Comment: @NaponFire: Works fine for me (Python 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing that width be an integer always in order to make you easy the comparation.
In this example i set width to -1 (int) as bad value to do the loop again

```
if option == "1":
        width = -1
        while  width < 1 or width>200:
            width = input("Enter rows (must be an integer between 1-200): ")
            if width.isdigit():
                width = int(width)
            else:
                width = -1
```